# Python Gensim LDA Model show_topics funciton

Tags: python, gensim, lda

I am training a LDA Model using Gensim:

```
dictionary = corpora.Dictionary(section_2_sentence_df['Tokenized_Sentence'].tolist())
dictionary.filter_extremes(no_below=20, no_above=0.7)
corpus = [dictionary.doc2bow(text) for text in (section_2_sentence_df['Tokenized_Sentence'].tolist())]

num_topics = 15
passes = 200
chunksize = 100
lda_sentence_model = gensim.models.ldamulticore.LdaMulticore(corpus, num_topics=num_topics, 
                                                              id2word=dictionary, 
                                                              passes=passes, 
                                                              chunksize=chunksize,
                                                              random_state=100,
                                                              workers = 3)
```

After training i need the topics for further analysis. Unfortunately the show_topics function only returns **10 topics**. I expected the defined number of **15 topics**. Does anyone know if that is on purpose or an error that can be solved?

```
print(len(lda_sentence_model.show_topics(formatted=False)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the gensim documentation for the `.show_topics()` method, its default `num_topics` parameter value ("Number of topics to be returned") is 10:

https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/ldamulticore.html#gensim.models.ldamulticore.LdaMulticore.show_topics

If you want it to return more than 10, supply your preferred non-default value for that method's `num_topics` parameter. For example:

```py
len(lda_sentence_model.show_topics(formatted=False, num_topics=15))
```